# ListActivity with String classes is unclickable

Tags: android, class, listactivity

I am using ListActivity with String classes, everything is fine except that they are unclickable. I want to use `ListActivity` with string classes not with `ListView`.  I want to bind my activity.java to activity. How to fix this?

```
package com.tutorial.android;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity{ 
String classes [] =   
{"example0", "example1", "example2", "example3", "example4", "example5", "example6"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String activity = classes[position];
    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.tutorial.android. " + activity);
    startActivity(new Intent (Menu.this, ourClass));
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

And this is manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.tutorial.android"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.tutorial.android.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.tutorial.android.Example0"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.tutorial.android.EXAMPLE0" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.tutorial.android.Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.tutorial.android.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you created Activity with the name example0, example1 and so on.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Did you mean `onListItemClick` is not called when a list item is clicked?

Comment: @Amit Gupta: Yes I did

Comment: @Born to Code: Yes exactly

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space after `com.tutorial.android.` on this line:

```
Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.tutorial.android. " + activity);
```

Change to

```
Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.tutorial.android." + activity);
```

Also, you have to implement the `Activity`s first and register them in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, otherwise the app cannot find the `Activity` when you click the list item.